# if statements on rows r

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I have currently have a data frame that is taken from a data feed of events that happened in chronological order. I would like to add a new column onto to each row of my data the corresponds to the next event's player_id if the event type is 1 & the outcome is 1

e.g

```
player_id <- c(12, 17, 26, 3)
event_type <- c(1, 3, 1, 10)
outcome <- c(1, 0, 1, 1)
df <- data.frame(player_id, event_type, outcome)
df
     player_id  event_type outcome
1        12          1       1
2        17          3       0
3        26          1       1
4         3         10       1
```

so end result

```
      player_id event_type outcome next_player_id
1        12          1       1             17
2        17          3       0             NA
3        26          1       1              3
4         3         10       1             NA
```

> 

Help much appreciated as I'm still in the beginners stage in r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `ifelse` with `lead`

```
library(dplyr)
res <- df %>% 
         mutate(next_player_id =  ifelse(outcome==1 & event_type == 1, 
                                                lead(player_id), NA))
res
#  player_id event_type outcome next_player_id
#1        12          1       1             17
#2        17          3       0             NA
#3        26          1       1              3
#4         3         10       1             NA
```

---

Or in `base R` with `transform` and `ifelse`

```
transform(df, next_player_id = ifelse(outcome == 1 & event_type==1, 
                c(player_id[-1], NA), NA))
```

EDIT: added the `&` condition based on @RHertel's comments

Or instead of `ifelse`, we can do this in 2 step process i.e. 1) creating a logical index, and 2) based on the index we assign the new column

```
i1 <- with(df, event_type == 1 & outcome ==1)
df$next_player_id[i1] <- c(df$player_id[-1], NA)[i1]
```